# Excluding fields in a search

Tags: search

Is it possible to exclude some fields when using search?

Getting the q parameter from the URL and searching the products section including all fields:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set results = craft.entries.section('products').search(query) %}
```

This searches all fields, included those for "related articles" and "related products". I need to exclude those from the search.

**Some experiments**

Works to exclude hits in relatedProducts but limits the fields being searched to the productName field:

```
craft.entries.section('products').search('productName:'~ query ~' -relatedProducts:'~ query)
```

Does not work - also returns the product with a related product matching the query:

```
craft.entries.section('products').search(query ~' -relatedProducts:'~ query)
```

and the same when trying to include several fields before excluding relatedProducts:

```
craft.entries.section('products').search('productName:'~ query ~' OR productDescription:'~ query ~' -relatedProducts:'~ query)
```

Also tried searching just in the relatedProducts, confirming that it returns only the product with a related entry matching the query:

```
craft.entries.section('products').search('relatedProducts:'~ query)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can now use the [`attribute`](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultSearchTermOptions) parameter in your search options, to set the fields the search term should apply to (feature introduced with Craft 2.5).

Unfortunatelly it's currently only possible to set a single attribute, but what you can do is to use the [Preparse plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) to add a field to your elements
where you collect / concatenate search terms from all relevant fields, then search in this field only.

The settings for your `searchTerms` Preparse field:

```
{{ entry.title }}
{{ entry.body }}
{{ entry.keywords }}
```

The search parameter:

```
{% set searchParam = {
    query: query,
    attribute: 'searchTerms'
    subLeft: true,
    subRight: true,
} %}
```

Answer (score 4):

What about including only those fields you want to search:

```
craft.entries.section('products').search('productName:'~ query ~' OR productDescription:'~ query ~' OR productFoo:'~ query ~' OR productBar:'~ query)
```

Yep I know, it's not very nice (but hey, it was you who started listing them). What you could do to make this ugly thing of a search parameter more manageable is to add the conditions programmatically:

```
{% set searchFields = [
    'productName',
    'productDescription',
    'productFoo',
    'productBar',
] %}

{% set searchParam %}

    {% for searchField in searchFields %}
        {{- not loop.first ? 'OR' -}}
        {{- searchField ~ ':' ~ query -}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endset %}

{% set results = craft.entries.section('products').search(searchParam|trim) %}
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried that too. Specifically: `craft.entries.section('products').search('productName:'~ query ~' OR productDescription:'~ query`and it also returns the product matching on relatedProducts. In fact it seems adding any `OR` in there makes it search every field. In the documentation, the `OR` examples searches for two different words, but always within the same field, like `body:salty OR body:dog` and `body:salty -body:dog`. So maybe this approach is not even supported.

Comment: @oyvind tried it with success?

Comment: Hit enter too early @carlcs - edit above :)

Comment: Hmm.. that's no good. Did you try rebuilding your search indexes with that tool in the CP settings?

Comment: @oyvind I just tested it and can confirm that it's not working. Seems like a bug to me though, that's why I did a [bug report on g+](https://plus.google.com/101325980081569498457/posts/WHjHahiEAsJ).

Comment: @oyvind tested the code with 2.2 and it now it works.

Comment: Great @carlcs - also got an email notification from Brandon at Pixel & Tonic about the fix being included in 2.2 - great and super fast support as always.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is working yet?

Comment: @ClivePortman yes, having problems getting it working?

Comment: @carlcs No, just wanted to check whether it was worth trying to use this. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ClivePortman ahh I see, it's not marked as accepted... People forget about that, I guess!